# Showing convergence rigourously

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

So I have $f_n(x) = x^{4n} + \frac1{n^2}$ which I know converges to $f(x)=0$ uniformly on interval $[0,1)$, but how can I show this with rigour?

Is this acceptably rigourous?
$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} x^{4n} + \frac1{n^2} =  \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} x^{4n} + \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n^2} = \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} x^{4n} + 0 = \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} x^{4n}$

$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} x^{4n} = 0$

Proof: $\forall x \in [0,1), \epsilon \gt 0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\gt N$

$x^{4n} \lt x^{4N}$

Set $\epsilon = x^{4N}$

Thus $x^{4n} \lt \epsilon$, hence $\forall x\in [0,1) $, $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} x^{4n} = 0 $

Hence, $f_n(x) = x^{4n} + \frac1{n^2}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1)$.

Comment: The convergence on $[0,1)$ is pointwise, not uniform.

Comment: yes it is not uniform..

Comment: I guess this  is not rigorous and not even acceptable (at least for me)... By "set $\epsilon = x^{4N}$" don't you think you are fixing $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Did Doesn't uniform convergence just mean it converges for all values in that range to the same value? In this case $0$?

Comment: No it does not. Please check your notes or your textbook or WP or whatever.

Comment: @Did Does my edit now make it converge uniformly?

Comment: @Examin5days for uniform convergence, you would have to consider an interval of the form $[0,a]$, where $a\lt 1$, since then there is some $N\in\Bbb N:\forall n\ge N:|x^n|=|x|^n\le|a|^n\lt\epsilon$. 

See now that the condition is uniform, since we have the upper bound $a$ to use.

Comment: @Ellya Here I can't choose an $a$ can I, and even if I included $1$ it would still be pointwise convergent, but only to $f(x)= 0, [0,1), f(x) = 1, x=1$

Comment: No it does not. Obviously you did not care to follow my advice to "check your notes or your textbook or WP or whatever" for a definition of uniform convergence. Where do you think this leads us?

Comment: @Did Your rude demeanour is unnecessary, and I did check the notes, I merely had problems understanding them, hence the question. I understand you are a high rep user, hence you answer a large number of questions, but I would rather go without your help if it is going to be greatly demotivating.

Comment: Are you saying that you checked your notes then revised your post and asked for my advice about the revision, although the revision continues to ignore superbly the very definition of uniform convergence? Really? You know what, if really you have an "exam in 5 days", this behaviour is not optimal (but if you prefer to kill the messenger, so be it).

Comment: @Did Thank you for these kind words.

Comment: @Examin5days, no you can't choose an $a$ for your question, I was just saying that if we were on an interval of the form $[0,a]$, we would have uniform convergence, but that would be the only way to have uniform convergence here, and since we do not have that, we do not have uniform convergence (what I have said should not be taken as a proof, but just as an observation).

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck for your exam in 5 days.

Comment: @Ellya Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @Examin5days no worries, happy to help, and I genuinely wish you well in your exam!

Comment: "Also, I would like to mention that this isn't my only account, but I will be asking some trivial questions, and I would find it embarrassing to ask them on my primary account(Due to these questions being outside of my primary field of knowledge in Mathematics)." Funny, I did not know that duplicate accounts were allowed on MSE.

Comment: @Did Just so you know, my definition from text was:
"We say $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $\Omega$ if for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, $\exists n$ such that $|f(x) - f_n(x)| \lt \epsilon$ for $\forall n \gt N$ and all $x\in\Omega$

What I was specifically failing on was that I was allowing $N$ to change to fit all $n$. But I didn't know what it was specifically that I was missing, so I couldn't pin it down.

Hence the editing in $f_n converges to f$ in edit.

Comment: This mishmash of English and maths symbols is prone to misinterpretations. I hope you have a more solid definition at hand.

Comment: Compare $$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\ \exists N\in\mathbb N,\ \forall n\geqslant N,\ \forall x\in\Omega,\ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\lt\varepsilon$$ and $$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\ \forall x\in\Omega,\ \exists N\in\mathbb N,\ \forall n\geqslant N,\ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\lt\varepsilon$$ Which one defines what?

Comment: @Did Is that truly $\forall n \geq N$ or is $\forall n \gt N$?

Comment: Irrelevant, replace $N$ by $N-1$ or $N+1$.

Comment: Say, why did you omit to answer this very simple question: *Which one defines what?*

Comment: @Did I wasn't sure what you mean by "Which one defines what?"

I think they both say the same thing.

For all $\epsilon$ greater than zero, there is some natural number $N$ such that for all $n$, and all $x$ we have an epsilon neighbourhood that contains the clusterpoint of convergence.

These two do mean the same thing correct? Or is it that I am setting $N$ before I set some $x$ that encompasses the interval?

Comment: Then we are back to square one and your understanding of continuity vs uniform continuity is still lacking (I was kind of suspecting that we were). No they are not the same thing. This also means you did not understand the (fully correct) accepted answer.

Comment: @Did I know how to solve any of the problems I am given of the type now(I have compared some alternative questions), I just don't know how to answer your question above. I (believe I) understand the accepted answer. I think the notation you used is the thing that is mostly confusing me, I am not strong in first order logic & quantifiers (?) (Which no doubt I will need to work on)

Comment: @Did I have read online that reading these quantified statements can require that in converting to English, that "Such that" is added between components. With that knowledge, the first statement leads to uniform convergence, whereas the second leads us to pointwise convergence. I imagine that was the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Please make up your mind: "they both say the same thing" or they do not? // "I know how to solve any of the problems I am given of the type now" Given your performance on this page, I very much doubt that. But hey, this is your problem...

Comment: @Did What is my problem? Thank you for your help Did, I now know how to read quantified statements. The difference between the two statements is that the second reads "For every $x$ and every $\epsilon$, which leads to pointwise, whereas the first leads you towards uniform. The reason for my confusion was that I read the two statements as a set of conditions without order, now I know order is relevant. Thank you very much, this was the root of the problem in the first place!

Comment: @Did Could you perhaps recommend me reading in regards to set theory and quantified statements?

Comment: To study set theory and quantified statements for themselves is not the quickest road. I would stay focused on basic real analysis, with the definitions of limits, continuity, uniform continuity, differentiability and the like. There are tons of free online sets of notes on the subject, [this one](http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2013/2645/13/AnalysisIIContDiffHT13_draft8Mar.pdf) seems decent.

Comment: @Did Is the Analysis I reading for this also readily available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a lot of your confusion on this question seemed to be about quantifiers, and I have a pre-written statement about how I understand quantifiers, I thought I could modify it slightly to be acceptable as an answer. I don't know if it will help you on a compressed timescale, but I've had success with it when tutoring students.

Fair warning: it's not exactly short.

[Throughout, $\exists$ means "there exists" and $\forall$ means "for all".]

---

One of the things that confuses new students about quantifiers is that the order of quantifiers is usually extremely important. When I was coming to grips with them I was influenced by many of my own teachers who collectively gave me a model of quantified statements as a game.

> In a definition or a theorem, there are quantifiers, and then there is a conclusion. Evaluate the quantifiers from left to right, using the following rules:
>
> - When there is a $\exists$, *you* get to choose an object satisfying the specified conditions (usually, belonging to a set).
> - When there is a $\forall$, your *opponent* gets to choose an object satisfying the specified conditions.
> - All of the choices are public at the instant they are made.
>
> You win if the conclusion is satisfied. Your opponent wins if it is not.

To be more concrete, consider the usual definition uniform convergence on metric spaces. Then we get the "uniform convergence game" for metric spaces $X$ and $Z$, a sequence of functions $f_n:X\to Z$, and a function $f:X\to Z$, which has rules defined in the following way:

$$\forall \varepsilon>0, ~~ \exists N\in\Bbb N, ~~ \forall n\in\Bbb N,\, n\geq N, ~~ \forall x\in X; ~~~~ d_Z(f_n(x), f(x))<\varepsilon. $$

> In this example, your opponent picks a positive real $\varepsilon$. Knowing that choice, you pick a natural number $N$, and then knowing your choice, your opponent picks a natural number $n\geq N$ and then an $x$ from the domain.

By analyzing the two players' strategies, the game shows its true usefulness. If the players play optimally, then the winner will be decided before play even begins. For example, in the uniform convergence game, the choice of $X, Z$, $f_n$ and $f$ will determine the winner if both parties play optimally.

Naturally ssociated to each game is a statement. For a definition, that will be something like* "[object] is [defined term]" (i.e. "$f$ is continuous" or "$G$ is open"). For a theorem, it is the more bland "The following is true: [quantifiers]; [condition]".

The statement is true if (and only if) you have a winning strategy in the associated game; a way to win regardless of your opponent’s choices. Often, especially for definitions, the truth will depend on some input parameters used in the statement. In the example, the statement is "$f_n$ converges to $f$", and the truth of this of course depends on $f_n$ and $f$ (and implicitly, $X$ and $Z$).

If you can explain why the strategy works, you have a proof of the statement. Simple as that.

From this model, some stubborn general trends become more palatable:

- The order of the quantifiers is usually critically important, since it determines what information players have when making decisions,
- but you can rearrange the order of two quantifiers if they are consecutive and of the same kind,
- *unless* the conditions that one variable (the later one!) must satisfy, contain the other in their description.
- If a $\exists$ is pulled closer to the beginning, you have less information when choosing that object, and so it's "harder" to win. What this means is that fewer** objects will let you win, which is to say that the condition has been strengthened.
- Similarly, if a $\exists$ is pulled closer to the end, you have more information, and so the condition has been weakened.

They even give a (very) rough outline as to how to build a proof:

- Each $\exists$ represents some kind of construction in the proof, and you can only use a variable in that construction if it comes earlier in the quantifier list.
- Your opponent is smart, and so you have to assume that $\forall$ variables are going to be chosen to make the proof as hard as possible.
- Game-you is smart, so you can start thinking at the conclusion and assume that you will get the $\exists$ variables with all the nice properties you want. Of course you must later make sure that it is possible to actually choose them in that way with the information that game-you has at the time.

For a more hands-on experience that doesn't require as much background, try the following four "theorems". Can you see which ones are true and which are false? Can you give a proof?

$$\forall x,~~ \forall y; ~~~~ x-y=0. \qquad\qquad \forall x,~~ \exists y; ~~~~ x-y=0.$$
$$\exists x,~~ \exists y; ~~~~ x-y=0. \qquad\qquad \exists x,~~ \forall y; ~~~~ x-y=0.$$

(For the pedantic: assume all $x$ and $y$ are chosen from the real numbers.)

Every statement in mathematics feels the influence of quantifiers, but often students are not taught to appreciate it early enough in their careers. This can make things very confusing. But at the same time, they are very simple to understand once you put some work into it. And when you do, you start to see that influence, and are a lot closer to being able to do math than you were when you were blind to it.

---

You made it! If you can spare the time (maybe after your exam?) then I would really appreciate feedback. You won't be the last one to hear this, so you can make the lives of future students a bit easier by being upfront about what you liked and what was confusing.

*By 'something like', I just mean that you don't strictly need this format, for instance "$E$ is an example of a Kakeya set", or "$X$ has the property of Baire" if the defined term doesn't have a verb form. Details.

**Or rather, "no more".

Comment: Of the four 'theorems' $\left[ \begin{align} F&T\\T&F \end{align} \right]$. Really good post, I like the idea of thinking of it as a game. This definitely clears up some of the theorems I was having trouble with, thank you. (I will give you better feedback after exam)

Answer (score 3):

There are so many complications in what you have  suggested as a proof..

First of all you are actually **fixing** one $x$ in $[0,1)$ and then you want to prove $x^{4n}\rightarrow 0$

for that you need to **find $N\in \mathbb{N}$** such that $x^{4n}<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$

It is enough if you choose $N$ such that $x^{4N}<\epsilon$ (**why??**)

How do you choose such $N$ ??

> Hint : Apply $\log$ on both sides..

P.S : If you really understood what i have said the very next thing that should strike to you is that

$$\text{**This convergence is not Uniform**}$$

Comment: I got it down to $x^n \lt \epsilon$, but I don't see how this means it isn't uniform convergence, since it implies what I already expect is true, is that $x^n$ = 0 for all $x\in[0,1)$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: may be you should read definition of uniform convergence one more time... what does it mean to say $x^n$ converges to $0$ uniformly is that given $\epsilon$ i have single $N$ which works for all $x$.. Do you think that happens here?

Comment: So because I would always have to choose a larger $N$ to actually get it to zero(and not just near zero), it doesn't converge uniformly? Since $.99999999\dots 99^N \to 0$ moves to zero with great reluctance, the $N$ has to be infinitely large? Whereas I should be able to choose some $N$ where the sequence has already converged. Okay, I think I understand now.

Comment: i do not really understood what you have said but if you are sure that you understood then it is fine...

Comment: @Examin5days, you seem to get it but not quite, the whole idea of uniform convergence is that there is some $N$, such that $\forall n\ge N$, $x^{n}\lt\epsilon$, notice that this is independent of the value of $x$.

for non uniform convergence, if $x$ changes then $N$ may need to change as well, which is the situation we have here.

Comment: @Ellya Yes! That makes sense. Very good call, since my $N$ relies on $x$, I can't pick an $N$ that is all encompassing.

Comment: @Examin5days Indeed! it is a subtle difference but it is very important, good luck with your exam in 5 days!

Comment: @ellya : Thank you for helping him and being on my side when i am not on line... :)

Comment: @Examin5days : good luck!

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, no worries, uniform convergence is a tricky topic (well really uniform anything) so I'm glad to help